# Sending email on sails with mailgun machine results in 'cannot call method' on sails.machines['...'].sendPlaintextEmail({...}

Tags: sails.js, mailgun, treeline

I have a sails project I have hooked up in treeline - after creating an object I want to send an email using the mailgun machine however receive the following error:

```
/Users/alexlunnon/Workspace/fclp/fclp/api/controllers/OfferController.js:48
   sails.machines['00ba429e-d255-4f44-8efc-af6f5cfa4942_0.3.1'].sendPlaint
                                                                ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'sendPlaintextEmail' of undefined
at Object.sails.machines._project_1691_0.0.15.create_offer.setEnvironment.exec.success (/Users/alexlunnon/Workspace/fclp/fclp/api/controllers/OfferController.js:48:86)
at afterwards (/Users/alexlunnon/Workspace/fclp/fclp/node_modules/machine/lib/intercept-exit-callbacks.js:131:21)
at voided [as _onTimeout] (/Users/alexlunnon/Workspace/fclp/fclp/node_modules/machine/lib/intercept-exit-callbacks.js:98:20)
at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:112:15)
```

In the controller I can see `sails.machines['00ba429e-d255-4f44-8efc-af6f5cfa4942_0.3.1'].sendPlaintextEmail({` is successfully called when an object is created. I can also see under the machines folder `00ba429e-d255-4f44-8efc-af6f5cfa4942_0.3.1` has been synced with `machinepack-mailgun` from treeline.

Trying to isolate the issue I am able to see that removing all dynamic content from the call to `sendPlaintextEmail` results in the same error - as does `sendHTMLEmail`. I am using angular to post the object through to the `OfferController.js`

Any tips or suggestions to debug this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely issue is that some dependencies did not properly install.  The easiest solution is to delete your `api/machines` folder completely and run `treeline lift` again to have the system automatically re-install the necessary dependencies.